# ADO.NET or Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, ado.net

I am building a forum, and it has got 4 tables: Users, Threads, Comments, Topics.

I established the connection and the pages.. I started using the ADO.net way to insert data and select data..but then I found that to make more complex manipulations i need to know SQL. So I was looking for another way, and I found that I can open Visual Studio 2010, add Linq to SQL file that produced object relational designer. I read about how to write code, and I saw that I simply need to use a using statement with `DataContext` object with a simple code to update, add, delete rows in the tables.

I wanted to know, what are the advantages of using one way of querying over another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ to SQL is part of the ADO.NET family of technologies. It is based on services provided by the ADO.NET provider model. You can therefore mix LINQ to SQL code with existing ADO.NET applications and migrate current ADO.NET solutions to LINQ to SQL. The following illustration provides a high-level view of the relationship.

[image]

---

Refer to the following:

[ADO.NET and LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386944.aspx)

[Advantages & Disadvantages of LINQ](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/linqtosql/thread/cd952b8e-4bc6-4be9-87d3-cec7fbe7a0d8)

[Performance of LINQ to SQL over Normal Stored procedure](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/3712aa37-d946-40ed-b72f-8f67a35709de)

[LINQ-to-SQL and Stored Procedures](http://www.dofactory.com/topic/1048/linq-to-sql-and-stored-procedure.aspx)

Comment: ooh, thanks. i want to abstain from sql. cause from the video i am watching now: http://www.asp.net/sql-server/videos/creating-and-using-stored-procedures . I can see that SQL is a whole new language. i built an application using linq (a small one).. all i need to know that i am not restricted to anything if i choose linq to sql. How can i convert sql to linq to sql?  part of the ADO.net framework uses objects like Reader,Dataset and linq to sql uses DataContext

Comment: Just drop the old objects. Read the following: [Programming Guide (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399408.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

ADO.NET gives you low level control over your queries. If query speed is going to be of importance, this is where you want to be. If you speed is not very important, but rapid development and an Object Relational Model is, LINQ to SQL is a safe bet.

I would recommend Linq to SQL over ADO.NET though.

1. Development is rapid and thinking in an ORM way is natural.
2. If your queries are too slow, using the .ExecuteQuery method will allow you to pass in a sql statement that you have optimized as if you were doing it in the ADO.NET way. I have had much success with Linq to Sql.

Also I would look at Entity Framework. It gives you more control over your objects and how they are implemented, used and handled than Linq.

Comment: I think you might have to bite the bullet and learn some SQL then. Linq to Sql can be quirky. I remember having a serious speed problem on inserts into large tables. Linq's default query would do an insert, and THEN a select for the identity that it just saved. It was far slower than just implimenting the Insert in sql

Comment: With any layer of abstraction you generally lose some control and execution speed...

Comment: I insert the users data once they register, and every time they click a link to open a thread or add a message. I will learn linq to sql, then if i see that i lose a lot of speed, i will learn SQL. I am doing a project for my course..

Comment: Linq to SQL should be fine for you.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to SQL is great in that it generates alot of the plumbing code for you. But it is basically the same as using straight up ADO.NET/SQL. To do more complex data manipulation in LINQ to SQL you have to know how write complex joins in LINQ just as you would in SQL.

Look into Entity Framework -  it might give you a higher level of abstraction that you are looking for.

Comment: +1 for letting OP know there's no shortcut for complexity. You gotta learn!!

Answer (score 1):

The two are on different abstraction levels. ADO.NET is the lowest level of data access in .NET. Anything else will build upon it.

Every abstraction should give you power to express higher-level concepts at the cost of lower level concepts.

If I sound like a philosopher it's because it's Friday.

Comment: So if i work on a higher level of data, i basically lose speed :(.. But it does mean if i chose to go for the sql approach, i need to concate complex command statements and learn sql..a language that i dont know right now :(

Comment: The speed loss may be negligible, but you can get yourself into situations where the code becomes very inefficient, yes.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Entity Framework, you can take a look at NHibernate (another .net Object Relational Mapper). It's been around longer than EF so it's a bit more mature, but it isn't developed by Microsoft if that matters to you.