# How to decide whether to use LINQ to SQL or ADO.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I am just wondering which of the above technology is to use and when with `SQL Server`

- What are the factors that can use to determine which technology is to use
- Will the performance of those technologies acting differently in web based application and standalone application.

Thanks

Comment: Related: Choosing a .NET ORM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/5995061/102937

Answer (score 3):

Well, Linq2Sql is additional layer on top on ADO.NET.
Here is comparison of ORM's for 4.0 .net:
[Best ORM to use with C# 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187928/best-orm-to-use-with-c-sharp-4-0)

I would also recommend EF over Linq2Sql, even if EF still does not have some simple things (like enum support).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an adventure use `Linq2Sql` but we have learn something about that.

I will suggest you to use `EntityFrameWork` if you are using .Net Framework 4.0.. In EntityFramework you can use Linq queries more well than Linq2Sql files.

`ADO.Net` is became old now and we need to learn new things now and then.